# Is there a simpler way to memoize a recursive let fn?

Tags: clojure

Let's say you have a recursive function defined in a let block:

```
(let [fib (fn fib [n]
            (if (< n 2)
              n
              (+ (fib (- n 1))
                 (fib (- n 2)))))]
  (fib 42))
```

This can be mechanically transformed to utilize `memoize`:

1. Wrap the `fn` form in a call to `memoize`.
2. Move the function name in as the 1st argument.
3. Pass the function into itself wherever it is called.
4. Rebind the function symbol to do the same using `partial`.

Transforming the above code leads to:

```
(let [fib (memoize
            (fn [fib n]
              (if (< n 2)
                n
                (+ (fib fib (- n 1))
                   (fib fib (- n 2))))))
      fib (partial fib fib)]
  (fib 42))
```

This works, but feels overly complicated. The question is: Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You should use TCO in this case (using `loop` as Clojure doesn't have TCO in common definition).

Comment: @hauleth This question is about how to apply memoization to an arbitrary recursive function defined in the context of a let block. This particular tree-recursive Fibonacci formulation is used only because it is a well known simple example illustrating the benefits of memoization. Definitely, stack-friendly computation of Fibonacci numbers would take a different approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take risks in answering since I am not a scholar but I don't think so. You pretty much did the standard thing which in fine is a partial application of memoization through a fixed point combinator.

You could try to fiddle with macros though (for simple cases it could be easy, syntax-quote would do name resolution for you and you could operate on that). I'll try once I get home.

edit: went back home and tried out stuff, this seems to be ok-ish for simple cases

```
(defmacro memoize-rec [form]
  (let [[fn* fname params & body] form
        params-with-fname (vec (cons fname params))]
    `(let [f# (memoize (fn ~params-with-fname
                         (let [~fname (partial ~fname ~fname)] ~@body)))]
       (partial f# f#))))

;; (clojure.pprint/pprint (macroexpand '(memoize-rec (fn f [x] (str (f x))))))
((memoize-rec (fn fib [n]
                (if (< n 2)
                  n
                  (+ (fib (- n 1))
                     (fib (- n 2)))))) 75) ;; instant

((fn fib [n]
                (if (< n 2)
                  n
                  (+ (fib (- n 1))
                     (fib (- n 2))))) 75) ;; slooooooow
```

simpler than what i thought!

Comment: The fixed point combinator aspect is interesting. Perhaps any approach to indirectly recursing via the result of the `memoize` call will either use such a combinator or alternatively introduce some global state (for example, this issue doesn't arise when not in a `let` block, and `def`ing a var, which provides the needed indirection.) So there probably is no _fundamentally_ simpler solution. But, syntactically, your macro is awesome. It nicely takes care of the mechanical transformation (without being a code-walking macro!), and leads to a result that is as simple as a `memoize` call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is "simpler" per se, but I thought I'd share an approach I took to re-implement `letfn` for a CPS transformer I wrote.

The key is to introduce the variables, but delay assigning them values until they are all in scope.  Basically, what you would like to write is:

`(let [f nil]
  (set! f (memoize (fn []
                     <body-of-f>)))
  (f))`

Of course this doesn't work as is, because `let` bindings are immutable in Clojure.  We can get around that, though, by using a reference type — for example, a `promise`:

`(let [f (promise)]
  (deliver! f (memoize (fn []
                         <body-of-f>)))
  (@f))`

But this still falls short, because we must replace every instance of `f` in `<body-of-f>` with `(deref f)`.  But we can solve this by introducing another function that invokes the function stored in the promise.  So the entire solution might look like this:

`(let [f* (promise)]
  (letfn [(f []
            (@f*))]
    (deliver f* (memoize (fn []
                           <body-of-f>)))
    (f)))`

If you have a set of mutually-recursive functions:

`(let [f* (promise)
      g* (promise)]
  (letfn [(f []
            (@f*))
          (g []
            (@g*))]
    (deliver f* (memoize (fn []
                           (g))))
    (deliver g* (memoize (fn []
                           (f))))
    (f)))`

Obviously that's a lot of boiler-plate.  But it's pretty trivial to construct a macro that gives you `letfn`-style syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a simpler way.
It is not a functional transformation, but builds on the impurity allowed in clojure.

```
(defn fib [n]
  (if (< n 2)
    n
    (+ (#'fib (- n 1))
       (#'fib (- n 2)))))

(def fib (memoize fib))
```

First step defines `fib` in almost the normal way, but recursive calls are made using *whatever the var `fib` contains*. Then `fib` is redefined,  becoming the memoized version of its old self.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose that clojure idiomatic way will be using `recur`

```
(def factorial
  (fn [n]
    (loop [cnt n acc 1]
      (if (zero? cnt)
           acc
         (recur (dec cnt) (* acc cnt))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ;; Memoized recursive function, a mash-up of memoize and fn
   (defmacro mrfn
      "Returns an anonymous function like `fn` but recursive calls to the given `name` within
      `body` use a memoized version of the function, potentially improving performance (see
      `memoize`).  Only simple argument symbols are supported, not varargs or destructing or
      multiple arities.  Memoized recursion requires explicit calls to `name` so the `body`
      should not use recur to the top level."
      [name args & body]
      {:pre [(simple-symbol? name) (vector? args) (seq args) (every? simple-symbol? args)]}
      (let [akey (if (= (count args) 1) (first args) args)]
        ;; name becomes extra arg to support recursive memoized calls
        `(let [f# (fn [~name ~@args] ~@body)
               mem# (atom {})]
           (fn mr# [~@args]
             (if-let [e# (find @mem# ~akey)]
               (val e#)
               (let [ret# (f# mr# ~@args)]
                 (swap! mem# assoc ~akey ret#)
                 ret#))))))


    ;; only change is fn to mrfn
    (let [fib (mrfn fib [n]
                (if (< n 2)
                  n
                  (+ (fib (- n 1))
                     (fib (- n 2)))))]
      (fib 42))
```

Timings on my oldish Mac:

original, Elapsed time: 14089.417441 msecs

mrfn version, Elapsed time: 0.220748 msecs